# Why are there white smudges on some of my film scans?

Tags: film

I just got back the negative scans from the first few hundred shots I took on my Minolta TC-1 with kodak gold. I've noticed that on some photos there is a white smudge near the bottom left corner of my shots. Is this a light leak problem? Any suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!

https://ibb.co/thYMm8q
https://ibb.co/SNnhwDR

Comment: Is the direction of the sun in all of the affected photos about 30-40 degrees above the horizon and to camera right?

Comment: Could you please post the images at a hosting site that allows direct linking, so that they could be visible in the question? (imgur, for instance.)

Comment: Photos can also be copy pasted in the post if kept at a reasonable size

Comment: @xenoid Without permission that's not really appropriate.

Comment: When inspecting the negatives, is there a corresponding "dark smudge" visible?

Answer (score 1):

Both of your examples look like they could be lens flare to me.

The sun is to the right and about 25-40 degrees above the horizon. The "smudge" is on the left of the frame below the left←→right center axis.